# Value only being updated once, what is wrong with my jquery code?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a table where a user clicks on image to block/unblock user. which is something  like this.

[image]

the html for the table (including the column for block/unblock) is retrieved via AJAX as i am using the jquery data table plugin.

here is the retrieved html for the column block/unblock

```
<td>
    <a class="toggle" href="#toggle">
        <img src="app/css/images/tick.png" alt="Yes" data-id="4" data-block="0">
    </a>
</td>
```

the data-table block represents the state of block/unblock, if the value is 0 then it shows an image called `tick.png` (enabled) else `tock.png`(disabled).

i am using the following jQuery to capture the click and send data to server side to get and make changes.

```
$('.toggle').live('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).find('img').data('id');
    var block =  $(this).find('img').data('block');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  "app/ajax/User/Block.php",
        data: 'id='+id+'&block='+block,
        success: function(data) {
            var image = (data == 1) ? 'app/css/images/tock.png' : 'app/css/images/tick.png';
            $('.toggle img[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('data-block', data);
            $('.toggle img[data-id="'+id+'"]').attr('src', image);
        }
    });
});
```

and here is the PHP code i am using.

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['block'])) {
    $userId = $_POST['id'];
    //$_POST['blocks'] holds the current value of block/unblock.
    //toggle the block/unblock state.
    $block = $_POST['block'] == 1 ? 0 : 1;
    User::blockUser(array($userId), $block);
    //Respond back toggled block/unblock value.
    echo $block;
}
```

everything works fine if i click the image toggles the state so as the `data-block` value get updated, the problem is i can click it only once, if i click the same image again it doesn't do anything. i checked the values in console, the values does not get updated too after the first click. what is wrong with the code?

**Update :**

Here is the HTML in the first stage before i.e before clicking.

```
<a class="toggle" href="#toggle">
    <img src="app/css/images/tick.png" alt="Yes" data-id="4" data-block="0">
</a>
```

here is the HTML after clicking the same row.

```
<a class="toggle row_selected" href="#toggle">
    <img src="app/css/images/tock.png" alt="Yes" data-id="4" data-block="1">
</a>
//Here the extra class row_selected is added by default by another plugin, do you think this is creating the problem?
```

and here it is again after first click.

```
<a class="toggle" href="#toggle">
    <img src="app/css/images/tock.png" alt="Yes" data-id="4" data-block="1">
</a>
```

Comment: did u check if the second img are receiving the same class `toggle` ?

Comment: sure thank you @Ghommey, i have updated my code,please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has its own data implementation:

You should use `.data('block', data);` instead of  `.attr('data-block', data);`
as you read it with `$(this).find('img').data('block')`

Also you shouldn't use jQuery for class detection like  `$('.toggle')` if you know the tag.
In your example you could easily improve the performance by using  `$('a.toggle')`

Comment: nope, that can't be a problem, because it have to toggle the current state on click i.e if the value is 0 change it to 1 and vice versa. i tried that code and if i do that it does not get updated at all.

Comment: I see. Use the jQuery data method as a setter.

Comment: wooow, thank you so so so very much, that was the bug, i should had used .`data()` instead of `.attr()`, it is working now, thank you once again @Ghommey

Comment: it works, but when i see console the `data-block` value only gets updated after a refresh, but the value in the database and the image gets updated.

Comment: Yes as I said before jQuery has it's own data implementation. So you can store arrays and objects with `.data('abc',{a:1})`. You won't see any the changes in the dom.